# Fluid mechanics problem concerning flow over a wedge

Tags: plotting

Below is the code I am using to generate a velocity profile and temperature profile for flow over a wedge.

```
sol[ξ_] := 
  NDSolve[{
   D[f[η], {η, 3}] + (m + 1)/2 f[η] f''[η] + m* (1 - (f'[η])^2) == 0,
   D[θ[η], {η, 2}] + f[η] θ'[η]*(m + 1)*0.5*0.7 == 0,
   θ[0] ==  1, θ[5] == 0, f[0] == -2/(m + 1)*bsp, 
   f'[0] == 0, 
   f''[0] == ξ}, 
   {f[η], θ[η], θ'[η]}, {η, 0, 9}] 

m = β/(2 π - β);
m = 0;
DFEnd[ξ_?NumericQ] := D[f[η] /. sol[ξ], {η, 1}] /. η -> 9
SOL1[bsp_] := FindRoot[DFEnd[ξ] == 1, {ξ, 0.5}]

plt1 = 
  Plot[Evaluate[
        Flatten[Table[D[f[η] /. sol[ξ /. SOL1[bsp]], {η, 1}], {bsp, 0, -1, -0.25}]] /. 
          η -> x], 
    {x, 0, 9},  
    PlotLegends -> Range[BSP = 0, BSP = -1, BSP = -0.25], 
    PlotRange -> All]
plt2 = 
  Plot[Evaluate[
         Flatten[Table[D[θ[η] /. sol[ξ /. SOL1[bsp]], {η,  1}], {bsp, 0, -1, -0.25}]] /. 
           η -> x], 
    {x, 0, 5}, 
    PlotLegends -> Range[0, 1, .25], 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

Here is how I am generating values of `f''[0]`, varying the `bsp` parameter for various values of `m`.

I wish to generate a table having values of `η` for which `f'[η]` is equal to 0.99 for  different values of `bsp` for a given `m`, and then I wish to vary `m` as well.

Let's say, for example, I first want a table for `m = 0`, where `bsp` ranges over `{-2.5,2.5,0.5}`; then `m = 1`, etc.

Is there a way to generate such a table for `f'[η] == 0.99` and similarly `θ'[0]` for different values of `m` and `bsp`.

Comment: Is there a way to solve f'[n]= 0.99. I am not able to use Solve function for that

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem, or is there some issue?

Comment: Hi Michael, it worked . Thanks alot for your answer

Comment: If you feel satisfied with an answer, you can [click the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/) to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You mention two parameters, `m` and `bsp`, but not the third `ξ`.  I will concentrate on solving `f'[η] == 0.99` for `ξ == 0.2`.  Use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) to set up the differential equations, and use [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html) to solve any ancillary equations that you wish, for example `f'[η] == 0.99`.  If you use `Sow` as I did, you need to turn the caching off, or the root will be sown only on the first call for the given parameters.

```
Clear[m, bsp, ξ, f, η];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {D[f[η], {η, 3}] + (m + 1)/2 f[η] f''[η] + m*(1 - (f'[η])^2) == 0,
   D[θ[η], {η, 2}] + f[η] θ'[η]*(m + 1)*0.5*0.7 == 0,
   θ[0] == 1, θ[5] == 0,
   f[0] == -2/(m + 1)*bsp, f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == ξ,
   WhenEvent[f'[η] == 0.99, Sow[η]]},
  {f, θ, Derivative[1][θ]},
  {η, 0, 9},
  {m, bsp, ξ},
  Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Flatten@Table[Last@Reap[sol[0, bsp, 0.2]] /. {} -> None, {bsp, -2.5, 2.5, 0.5}]
(*
  {None, None, None, None, None, None, 2.70527, 1.83437, 1.44146, 1.20493, 1.04352}
*)
```

If you don't want to use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html), the equation may be solved after getting the solution to the differential equation like this:

```
With[{f = First[sol[0, 1., 0.2]]},
 FindRoot[
  f'[η] == 0.99, {η, 1}]
 ]
(*
  {η -> 1.83437}
*)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. It really helped me alot

Comment: You're welcome!